# React Redux re-fetch data using state and state change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I would like to pass data from my state to a fetch call (e.g. search term). When the state changes, it should re-fetch my data.

The lifecycle methods seem to be the place to do this, but when I use them it either does nothing (render is called before state change), or it goes on an endless loop.

Here is my simplified code:

```js
@connect((store) => {
    return {
        collections : store.collections.collections
    }
}, {
    fetchCollections
})
export default class CollectionPane extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
           term : null
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.handleFetchCollections(this.state.term);   // This loads initial ok
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        // this.handleFetchCollections(this.state.term);  // This causes loop
    }

    handleFetchCollections(props, sort){
        log('Fetching...', 'green');
        this.props.fetchCollections(props, sort);
    }

    onSearch(){
  
  const term = "test example";
  
  this.setState({
   term
  })
    }

    render(){
        const { collections } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <a style={{ display: "block", padding: "1em" }} onClick={this.onSearch.bind(this)}>Search</a>

                <CollectionList collections={collections} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should compare your new state with the previous state before performing fetch:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.term !== this.state.term) {
        this.handleFetchCollections(this.state.term);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With react-redux you should change your state through actions and reducers. Then you can use async actions as described here: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

Comment: I would be interested if you had an example of what you mean